# JAXB validation - difference between jaxb 1.0 vs jaxb 2.0

Tags: java, validation, jaxb

In Jaxb 1.0 the xml validation is turned on by calling 'setValidating' on unmarshaller object:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(packageName);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setValidating(true);
```

In Jaxb 2.0 the validation is enhanced and setting up a schema is required:

```
 Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(file);
 unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

Looks like to use JAXB 2.0 validation the schema xsd file is a **neccessary, requisite** resource that must be provided in the application context.

While in JAXB 1.0 to turn on validation the schema file is not required (at least explicitly)

Question 1:

Does JAXB 1.0 really stores validation capabilities in its implementation (which comes from xjc) and xsd file is not required in the app/package/classpath runtime context?

Question 2:

In JAXB 2.0 is it possible to *'unsetSchema'* for the unmarshaller - just give up validation (for performance purposes ... when I see that incoming xml payload is the same like the one I already validated earlier)?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question #2:

To turn off unmarshaller validation it is enough to reset schema to null:

```
unmarshaller.setSchema(null);
```

Question #1 remains open:

Does JAXB 2.0 need a schema file to be provided at runtime to perform validation during marshalling/unmarshalling ? ... or maybe we can force xjc complier with some options (like -nv) to generate implementation that has validation capabilities like JAXB 1.0 used to have. (just not to disclose xsd schema)